# HTML GET Form with Fixed Predefined Values

Tags: html, forms, get

I want to set up an HTML Form which will submit (via GET) a combination of user-entered and predefined values.

To explain with a basic example, see this form:

```
<form action=“/test.html“ method=“get”>
<input type=“text” name=“foo”>
<input type=“submit” value=“SUBMIT">
</form>
```

This form would give the url `/test.html?foo=____`, where the underline is whatever the user entered.

What I want to do is also have other values which are set by me and not the user, such as `/test.html?foo=____&bar=presetvalue`.

I have tried setting `action=“/test.html?bar=presetvalue”`, but that doesn’t work.

I could potentially do this with hidden fields, but that seems like a messy way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have tried setting `action="/test.html?bar=presetvalue"`, but that doesn’t work.

Submitting a GET form generates a new query string which replaces any existing query string.

> I could potentially do this with hidden fields, but that seems like a messy way to do it.

This is **exactly** what hidden fields are designed for. They are the correct tool for the job.